# https node js socket hangup too much get request, how to handle it?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to **scrape** a list of hardlink from website. But it stop in progress. it just get only like 40 - 60 hardlink and it starts to hang up with error. how to handle this?

```
const https = require('https');
const htmlparser = require('node-html-parser');

const urls = [];

// A bunch list pages to scrape
for(let i = 2; i < 753; i++){
  urls.push('https://hentairead.com/page/' + i + '/');
}

for(url of urls){
  const req = https.get(url, res => {
    if(res.statusCode == 200){
      var buffer = '';

      res.on('data', d => {
        buffer += d;
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
        const root = htmlparser.parse(buffer);
        const elements = root.querySelectorAll('div.page-item-detail-wrapper');

        for (element of elements){
          const atrib = element.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].attributes;

          console.log(atrib.href);
        }
      });

      res.on('error', (e) => {
        console.error(e);
      });
    }
  });

  req.end();
}
```

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ not scrap

Comment: can you post the error messages too?